# Change x axis to scale with pi and not numbers

Tags: plot, octave

I want to create the plot of cos(x) and sin(x) in Octave. I have learned how to change things such as xlabel  and xlim, however I can’t find how to change from having numbers (e.g 1, 2, 3) to having pi terms (-pi,-pi/2 and such). I would also appreciate if you can explain me how to do that. Here is a picture of what I want to do in case my english confused you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Matlab you can do something like this:

```
set(gca,'XTick',-pi:pi/2:pi)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'-pi','-pi/2','0','pi/2','pi'})
```

As you can see here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-axis-parameters.html

This should work in Octave as well.

Also I haven't tested this but to get the actual Pi symbol you might try:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'-p','-p/2','0','p/2','p'}, 'fontname','symbol')
```

Otherwise you can try and see if this Matlab FEX submission will work for you: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15986

Comment: thx a lot! i was able to get the x axis scale with pi. now i am working on y axis because it will show from -1 to -0,5 and not ever -0,2 like the photo. do you have any suggestion on that as well? :D but thx anyway it was a big help!

Comment: `set(gca,'YTick',-1:0.2:1)`

Comment: For the actual "pi" symbol you have to use this (at least on my system): `set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'-p','-p/2','0','p/2','p'}, 'fontname','symbol')`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. For the actual symbol pie, I replaced `set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'-pi','-pi/2','0','pi/2','pi'})` with `set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'-π','-π/2','0','π/2','π'})`

Answer (score 2):

For the π symbol you only have to write \pi.

`set(gca,'XTick',-pi:pi/2:pi)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'-\pi','-\pi/2','0','\pi/2','\pi'})`

Answer (score 2):

This is an old topic, but here is an Octave solution with a bit of context.

Shadowing @Dan's input with @Chimalis's revision, the following script works in Octave 4.4.1 on Windows and 5.2.0 on Linux. Pay particular attention to the use of xtick, xticks, xticklabel, and xticklabels.

```
x = linspace(-3*pi,3*pi);
figure;
hold on;
subplot(2,1,1);
y = cos(x);
plot(x,y)
ylabel('cosine');
xticks([-3*pi -2*pi -pi 0 pi 2*pi 3*pi]);
xticklabels({'-3\pi','-2\pi','-\pi','0','\pi','2\pi','3\pi'});
yticks([-1 -0.866 -0.707 -0.5 0 0.5 0.707 0.866 1]);
grid on;
sp_h2 = subplot(2,1,2);
z = sin(x);
plot(x,z)
sp_h2_pos = get(sp_h2, 'Position');
sp_h2_pos_new = sp_h2_pos - [0 0 sp_h2_pos(3)/2 0];
set(sp_h2, 'Position', sp_h2_pos_new);
ylabel('sine')
xlim([0 2*pi]);
h=get (gcf, "currentaxes");
set(h,"xtick",0:pi/2:2*pi);
set(h,"xticklabel",['0';'\pi/2';'\pi';'3\pi/2';'2\pi']);
```